# How can I allow a user to post images and documents?

Tags: html, css

We want to make a website where users can post things, We've made a chat system but want to allow the user for posting documents and images as well. Does anyone know how to do that?

I searched here if someone already had this problem, but I didn't see anyone.

```
<script src="http://localhost/chat.html"></script>

<div class="chatcontainer">
  <div class="chatheader">
    <h3>Welcome<?php echo ucwords($user); ?></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="chatmassages"></div>
  <div class="chatbottom">
    <form action="#" onsubmit="return false;" id="chatform">
      <input type="hidden" id="name" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" />
      <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" placeholder="type your chat massage" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="post" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think I need to add one more button, but how does that code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
<input type=“file” accept=“.jpg,.png etc”>
```

Check this link for further info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file.